# How do I display data in a Ruby on Rails site in left and right columns of HTML table?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, multiple-columns

In my Ruby on Rails application I want to display half the data from one table in the database in a left column in a HTML table and the other half in the right column. What I have only been able to is display the data with an id of 1 in a left cell and then in a right cell in the same row and then data with an id of 2 in a left cell then again in a right cell in the next row:

```
<table>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <tr>
            <% if category.id == 1  %>
                <td bgcolor="#03FF00">
                    <%= category.id %>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#f1f1c1">
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Show', category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Destroy', category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>  
                </td>
            <% end %>
            <% if category.id == 1  %>
                <td bgcolor="#03FF00">
                    <%= category.id %>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#f1f1c1">
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Show', category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Destroy', category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>  
                </td>
            <% end %>                               
            <% if category.id == 2  %>
                <td bgcolor="#03FF00">
                    <%= category.id %>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#f1f1c1">
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Show', category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Destroy', category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </td>
            <% end %>
            <% if category.id == 2 %>
                <td bgcolor="#03FF00">
                    <%= category.id %>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#f1f1c1">
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Show', category_path(category) %>&nbsp;|
                    <%= link_to 'Destroy', category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>  
                </td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>   
    <% end %>                           
</table>
```

I have been trying this for ages and that piece of code was the best that I could come up with, but doesn't work when I try to use it to show half in one side and half on the other, which I have attempted to do using:

```
if category.id <= Category.count / 2
```

and

if category.id > Category.count / 2

Which I know in itself isn't a very efficient or 'safe' way of calculating due to using the id and not the row number.

In my categories table I have two columns: id and genre, but I want to display only the genre of each category and the links: Edit, Show, and Destroy for each one.

Any ideas? Please try to show me the code rather than tell me where to place code.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Could you show us an example of what you have in `@categories` and what you want the final table to look like (e.g. with an ASCII table)?

Comment: what's the datatable that you're trying to show in html?

Comment: I want the final table to have 4 columns, e.g. genre | Add, Edit, Destroy | genre | Add, Edit, Destroy. And then as many rows as needed to display all of the data in the categories table. I have added to the question to explain what is in the categories table. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I am trying to show the categories datatable

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is you want to display the same rows of table in two parts on the page. So I would suggest you to make two tables one for the left and one for the right. And play with css. In the table left give:

```
float: left
```

and in the table right give:

```
float: right
```

Also you can play with position and other attributes of css. Or the next option is to make four columns but I am not sure as your question is a bit unclear.

Or if you just need to calculate then go with even and odd numbers. Ruby provides method for checking even and odd. Eg:

```
a = 1
a.odd?
a.even?
```

Update:

A code snippet for float left and right:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .left{
                float: left;
            }
            /*Optional*/
            .right{
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="left">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <td>Deep</td>
                <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="right">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <td>Deep</td>
                <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using float:right/left doesn't make a difference, the tables appear one below the other